# Import "google.oauth2.credentials" could not be resolved Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use google.oauth2, google_auth_oauthlib.flow and googleapiclient.discovery for my web app. But I'm getting these errors:

```
Import "google.auth.transport.requests" could not be resolved
Import "google.oauth2.credentials" could not be resolved
Import "googleapiclient.discovery" could not be resolved
```

And output is : from google.auth.transport.requests import Request ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
Here's my pip list :

```
    google                   3.0.0
    google-api-core          2.8.2
    google-api-python-client 2.51.0
    google-auth              2.8.0
    google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
    google-auth-oauthlib     0.5.2
    googleapis-common-protos 1.56.3
    gspread                  5.4.0
    httplib2                 0.20.4
    oauth2client             4.1.3
    oauthlib                 3.2.0
    requests                 2.28.0
    requests-oauthlib        1.3.1
```

I don't understand why am I getting these errors. I hope you'll help me.

Comment: Please post the actual text of the errors and your pip list, images are hard to use for debugging.

Comment: VS Code cannot find the google module. But it is available in pip and pip3 lists. I'm getting ReportMissingError : Import "google_auth_oauthlib.flow" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

Comment: Please edit your question to remove the images of text; do not write the error messages in a comment, as those don't format too well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe there is more than one python environment on your machine, please use **CTRL + SHIFT + P** to open the command palette type and select **Python: Select Interpreter** (or click on the interpreter version displayed in the lower right corner).

[image]

Choose the correct python interpreter and this will solve your problem.

Comment: I had to make sure the python version I used to create my virtual environment (venv) matched the VSCode interpreter version.